# Make all controls on a form read-only at once without one LinkButton

Tags: asp.net

I make all controls on a form read-only at once:

```
    private static void DisableControl(Control control)
    {
        PropertyInfo enProp = control.GetType().GetProperty("Enabled")
        if (enProp != null)
        {
            enProp.SetValue(control, false, null);
        }

        foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.ID != "HyperLinkExcelOrder")
                DisableControl(ctrl);

        }
    }
```

I don't want disable HyperLinkExcelOrder, but this function disabled it.
When I use HyperLinkExcelOrder.Enabled=true; It still is disabled.

Comment: Why do you use reflection at all when you are processsing only `Controls`? They definitely have an `Enabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set enabled = false on the from. Child Enabled properties will take the value of their parent automaticly. And then set the Hyperlink control on enabled = true. There is not need for DisableControl code.

Comment: just test it. And see it is not so much work as you think. Less is more.