# How do I make all controls on a Delphi form non editable/changeable but still allow user to copy contents

Tags: delphi, copy, readonly

I have a form displaying data from a database, It has a few buttons and several panels. The panels contain a variety of components, specifically TEdits, TComboBox, TDateTimePicker, TCheckBox, TListBox and TstringGrid.

When the form is opened such that the user can view, but not edit, the data I currently disable all the components except for the buttons using

```
for i := 0 to FrmAddNewMember.ComponentCount-1 do
    if FrmAddNewMember.Components[i] is TPanel then
      (FrmAddNewMember.Components[ i ] as TPanel).enabled := false;
```

This works fine except that I would now like the user to be able to copy to the clipboard the text in the TEdits, the date in the TDateTimePicker, the selected item in the TComboBox etc etc. but still not change it.

I altered the code to the following which sets the TEdits to Read Only. This does what I want for TEdits but the other type of controls do not have a read only property, so I disabled them as before.

```
for i := 0 to FrmAddNewMember.ComponentCount-1 do
    if not (FrmAddNewMember.Components[i] is TButton) then //(keep buttons working)
       case FrmAddNewMember.Components[i] of
          TEdit: (FrmAddNewMember.Components[ i ] as TEdit).readonly := true; //allows copying but not editing
          TComboBox: (FrmAddNewMember.Components[ i ] as TComboBox).enabled := false;  //no read only propert?
          TDateTimePicker: (FrmAddNewMember.Components[ i ] as TDateTimePicker).enabled := false;  //ditto
          TCheckBox: (FrmAddNewMember.Components[ i ] as TCheckBox).enabled := false;
          TListBox:  (FrmAddNewMember.Components[ i ] as TListBox).enabled := false;
          TstringGrid: (FrmAddNewMember.Components[ i ] as TstringGrid).enabled := false;
       end;
```

Is there a way to make the other controls non editable but still allow their contents to be copied to the clipboard?

PS
I have looked at

[disable-edits-on-datagridview-but-still-allow-for-highlighting-to-copy-and-paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860881/disable-edits-on-datagridview-but-still-allow-for-highlighting-to-copy-and-paste)

and

[make-all-controls-on-a-form-read-only-at-once-without-one-linkbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564892/make-all-controls-on-a-form-read-only-at-once-without-one-linkbutton)

and searched elsewhere. Maybe it cannot be done simply.

Comment: Isn't that small edit to my title a little pedantic if you don't also attempt to answer the question? I put the word Delphi there on purpose as I am fed up searching the web for questions/answers involving Delphi and finding some SO ones that look relevant but then turn out to be for a different language. SO may use the tags but Google doesn't.

Comment: Why aren't you using database conrols like TField, TDateTimeField, TMemoField, TBooleanField, etc. All of them have Readonly property to control whether they can be changed or not

Comment: "Why aren't you using database controls... " Because the exe is a front end to a remote MySQL database (and is used by several people). The form does a great deal of processing and much of what it displays is processed or formatted data from the database. It is not merely a simple 'window' on the raw database data.

Comment: Strange design to disable component and allow to copy data from it.

Comment: @Dima  The controls are all disabled in this view as I use the same layout for both editing and viewing (view has the controls disabled to prevent accidental changes). It's handy for the user to be able to copy things like an email address or reference number to use elsewhere. This can  be done from the 'editing' form but there is a risk of altering the data, which would surprise the user when they closed the form and got a message asking them if they want to save changes. Hence I wanted to also allow such copying of data from the safer 'view' form where all the controls are disabled.

Comment: @Dima: not at all. It makes sense if you want to disable editing but still make the values available and copyable. That is why TEdit's ReadOnly would be a good solution, but not all controls support that.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Now I see your problem more clearer but still stay at my opinion.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I agree with disabling component to restrict editing (like in your example), but not agree with it *real* disabling (what `TPanel.Enabled ;= false` does). Personally, if I would write such a program, I would create my own components (derived from standard) with special property that will allow properly disable them keeping ability to copy info from them. Of course this way would cost some time (and money) but It would be better for further program maintenance.

Comment: What I would do depends on what I need. It I only need it once or twice, I would use a solution that does what @dwrbudr proposes. If I'd need it often, I'd write my own derived controls. In FMX, that may not even be necessary. There, I'd first try to modify the styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you can **emulate** a popup menu for your components (because standard popup menu will not work for disabled ones).

But if you will have popup menu for the form and `FormMouseDown` event handler, you can analyze where mouse pointer is (under which component, I mean) and call popup with `Copy` menu item.

Quick example for listboxes:

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Clipbrd;

type
  TForm6 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    ListBox2: TListBox;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    miCopy: TMenuItem;
    procedure miCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    selectedText: string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form6: TForm6;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := 1;
  ListBox2.ItemIndex := 1;
  Panel1.OnMouseDown := FormMouseDown;
end;

procedure TForm6.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  i, parentX, parentY: integer;
  p: TPoint;
  lb: TListBox;
begin
  if Button <> mbRight then
    exit;

  selectedText := '';
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    if Components[i] is TListBox then
    begin
      lb := TListBox(Components[i]);
      begin
        p := lb.ParentToClient(Point(X, Y));
        if lb.ClientRect.Contains(p) then
        begin
          parentX := 0;
          parentY := 0;
          if Assigned(lb.Parent) then
          begin
            parentX := lb.Parent.ClientOrigin.X;
            parentY := lb.Parent.ClientOrigin.Y;
          end;

          if lb.ItemIndex > -1 then
          begin
            selectedText := lb.Items[lb.ItemIndex];
            PopupMenu1.Popup(lb.Left + parentX + p.X, lb.Top + parentY + p.Y);
          end;
          break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm6.miCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if selectedText = '' then
    exit;

  Clipboard.AsText := selectedText;
end;

end.
```

Here `ListBox1` is placed on the `TPanel` component. Please note you should assign form's `OnMouseDown` handler to all your panels or other containers. Also, if you have nested containers, you need use recursive algorithm to find `parentX, parentY`.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like an interesting idea. I was thinking more along the lines of using Ctrl C and shortcuts like that but a proper pop up menu with just Copy on it would do the job. Any hints on implementation?

Comment: I'm not sure you can realize work with shortcuts because disabled controls doesn't get focus.

Comment: Good answer (didn't test it though) but it might be world of pain to adapt that code for *every* needed component as they have different data properties (`TListBox` and `TDateTmePicker` as example).

Comment: @Dima, not too much, I hope. Some controls can be casted to their parent, and we can use `Text` property.

Comment: `TListBox` and `TStringGrid` will return *empty* string after their casting. By the way `Text` property is `protected`, so OP needs to use non-trivial casting to get access to `Text` property. I hope he knows what he is doing))

Comment: @Dima, thus I wrote "some controls" :)

Comment: Thanks, yes I do have a reasonable idea of what I'm doing. Just didn't consider doing it this way. I thought I'd have to assign the form's OnMouseDown handler to all the panels in order to capture it but fortunately there is only one level of nesting so it needn't be recursive (although in my experience recursive solutions are often simple and elegant), I'll accept this answer as it gets me a long way towards what I am trying to do. Thanks Miamy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make combobox read-only. Also you can use the same approach to other edits if you can obtain the window handle of the edit.

```
procedure MakeComboboxReadOnly(const ACombobox: TCombobox);
var cbi: TComboBoxInfo;
begin
    cbi.cbSize := SizeOf(cbi);
    GetComboBoxInfo(ACombobox.Handle, cbi);
    SendMessage(cbi.hwndItem, EM_SETREADONLY, 1, 0);
end;
```

Comment: This code prevents user custom input only, but a combobox still allows to select items from its list.

Comment: To prevent user from selecting another item - set combobox Style := csSimple

Comment: or csDropDownList. I know, but it is not acceptable for all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a closure to my own question. The way I did it in the end was to simply place speed buttons next to the controls containing the text I wanted to copy and used the normal

```
uses ClipBrd;
...
Clipboard.AsText := MyControl1.text;
```

to copy the data.

The trick though was not to place the speed buttons as children of the panel containing the control, (which is disabled, hence also disabling all the controls inside it) but instead to just place them on the form and then move them so they are positioned in front of the panel next to the relevant control.

That way the speed buttons look like they are part of the panel yet will still operate when the panel and all it's controls are disabled.